# Version management and continous deployment with Appian?

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-deployment, appian

I recently learned about a low-code platform by **[Appian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appian_Corporation)** - it is basically a web service which allows you to click-and-drag interfaces, design processes using [bpmn](/questions/tagged/bpmn), and connect various data sources. Before I get too excited, I would like to figure out whether you could be working with this service fulfilling at least some check points of the [Joel Test](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/)

> 1. Do you use source control?
> 2. Can you make a build in one step?
> 3. Do you make daily builds?
> 4. Do you have a bug database?
> 5. Do you fix bugs before writing new code?
> 6. Do you have an up-to-date schedule?
> 7. Do you have a spec?
> 8. Do programmers have quiet working conditions?
> 9. Do you use the best tools money can buy?
> 10. Do you have testers?
> 11. Do new candidates write code during their interview?
> 12. Do you do hallway usability testing?

Most importantly, I am worried about the first point: **How do I do advanced version management? Can I easily do pull requests like in GIT?**

I heard that exported files of an Appian are loads of JSONs in a ZIP-file, so I might be able to actually use this in a usual GIT respository - or can I?

### References

- https://github.com/appian/devops-quickstart says it is *intended to serve as a model for Appian developers looking to construct a CI/CD pipeline in order to version and test their applications.* This project dates back to 2018, at does not look official.
- [Appian Docu: Managing Object Versions](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/19.4/Managing_Object_Versions.html) is not what I am after
- [Appian Playbook: Deployment Automation](https://community.appian.com/w/the-appian-playbook/198/deployment-automation) is a rather lengthy recipe for the usage of certain tools, and looks like it is in principle possible, but complicated.
- [Appian Community: Does anyone have an example of how they implemented GitHub/Jenkins for environment promotion?](https://community.appian.com/discussions/f/best-practices/12458/does-anyone-have-an-example-of-how-they-implemented-github-jenkins-for-environment-promotion) does refer to the above mentioned playbook.

**Disclaimer:** I am not associated with the service, I am just curious, and web searches did not lead me anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little more than a year ago, I worked in a project where we used Appian 18.x. Appian provides `Automated Versioning Manager` that helps manage Appian applications and database DDL files in a version control system. It will `unzip` the application and take care of `check-ins` and `check-outs`. It's a command-line utility. There's another tool called `Automated Import Manager` that takes care of deployment.

You can check this link for details: https://community.appian.com/b/appmarket/posts/deployment-automation-manager

As far as pull-request/code-review is concerned, I don't think there's any straightforward process. I guess it's mainly because of XMLs. Code review is mostly based on review checklists (manual) and the Appian Health Check (programmatic). Seems, there is one tool called [Virtual Application Review](https://community.appian.com/b/appmarket/posts/virtual-application-review) but that's 3rd party (and paid one). May be Appian might come up with [some solution](https://community.appian.com/discussions/f/general/18573/build-automated-code-review-tool-for-appian-application/73129#73129) in the near future.

`Automated Versioning Manager` never saw the light of the day in our project because the project was over before it could be implemented. :(

Comment: @Technexyt Thanks for all the hints and for mainly confirming what I was experiencing (with the little experience I have on Appian) about advanced version management.

Answer (score 2):

Working now since sept 2018 with Appian.
We developped multiple applications.

**Do you use source control?**

With the latest version of Appian version control is controlled in the admin control.You can see all deployments and stages of a package and who deployed.

We also have integrated the Appian deployments with Azure.

**Can you make a build in one step?**

This can be easilly done by the Appian compare environments options.
You can compare all components between environments, handle the security for all objects and see if there are missing components.

**Do you make daily builds?**
Yes, sometimes multiple a day

**Do you have a bug database?**
We have created something by ourself, which suits our purpose.

**Do you fix bugs before writing new code?**
Yes

**Do programmers have quiet working conditions?**
Depends, which have a DevOps teams, so sometimes the Ops part takes a bit of time.

**Do you have testers?**
No, technical testing is done in our team. Later in the acceptance test we use our business employees to test the new features.

**Do new candidates write code during their interview?**
No, but going to use it next time